# Vee-Validate - check if input is filled

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I am using [vee-validate](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v4/) in my project, (updating password page)

I want to display hide/show toggler icon **only when input filed is filled**, is there any way to do this without using ref?
[image: check this image]

my code:

```html
<div">
    <Field
        name="old_password"
        :type="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'"
        id="old_password"
        rules="required"
    />
    <v-icon
        @click="showPassword = !showPassword"
        class="pointer toggler-icon2"
        name="hideShowToggler"
    />
</div>
<div class="error-div">
    <ErrorMessage name="old_password" v-slot="{ message }">
        <p class="error">{{ message }}</p>
    </ErrorMessage>
</div>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: What is `Field`?, Use `v-if="passwordFieldValue"`

Comment: <Field is vee-valida's defined component, just input component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add v-model to Field tag and add v-if to v-icon:

```html
    <div>
        <Field
            name="old_password"
            :type="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'"
            id="old_password"
            :rules="required"
            v-model="passwd"
        />
        <v-icon
            @click="showPassword = !showPassword"
            class="pointer toggler-icon2"
            name="hideShowToggler"
            v-if="passwd"
        />
    </div>
```

You also need return passwd in your data function:

```js
      data() {
        return {
          passwd: "",
        }
      }
```

I don't know how do that without refs or data return :(

Edit:
You can add v-on directive that trigger function on any keyup on password field:

```html
    <div>
        <Field
            name="old_password"
            :type="showPassword ? 'text' : 'password'"
            id="old_password"
            :rules="required"
            v-on:keyup="passwdChecker"
        />
        <v-icon
            @click="showPassword = !showPassword"
            class="pointer toggler-icon2"
            name="hideShowToggler"
            v-if="passwd"
        />
    </div>
```

But you still need v-if and a passwd variable, but this time it's a boolean variable:

```js
  data() {
    return {
      passwd: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    passwdValue() {
      if ($("#old_password").val()) this.passwd = true;
      else return (this.passwd = false);
    }
  },
```

Of course you don't need to use jQuery. I hope I helped.